# call then only after method returning promise is finished

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise, filereader

```
submitTCtoDB() {
  console.log("this.selectedFileList is:  " + this.selectedFileList)
  this.readFile().then(() => {
    alert("ReadFile Finished now submit TC");
    this.submitTC()
  });
}

readFile() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFileList.length; i++) {
      let file = this.selectedFileList[i];
      alert("file in redafile" + file.name)
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        this.fileContent = fileReader.result;
        if (this.fileContent.indexOf("END DATA | BEGIN RESULTS") != -1) {
          alert("Multiple testcases found in " + file.name + " file.  Please separate/save testcases in Calc Builder. Then reimport");
          const index: number = this.selectedFileList.indexOf(file);

          if (index > -1) {
            this.selectedFileList.splice(index, 1);
          }

          console.log(this.fileContent);

        }
        resolve(this.fileContent);
      }
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
    }
  });
}
```

I want to run the submitTC() method only after the readFile method is completely finished but .then(inside submitTCtoDB) is getting invoked early .

I think .then or promise is not used properly.

Desired functionality is to call the submitTC method only when readFile method is completed reading/splicing the files. 
Kindly help.

Comment: Don't put that loop, don't put *any* functionality but the single asynchronous call inside the `new Promise`. Then use promise mechanics to put everything together.

Comment: @Bergi But i need to pass all the files 1 by 1 to the fileReader.Then what to do?

Comment: Write one function that takes a single file and reads it. Write another function that processes the file list.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot i will try it..can i keep the for loop in submitTCtoDB method and call the readFile method evrytime for the loop

Comment: Yes, please try that, it's the first step towards using promises properly in any case :-) I'm not sure though what the method is supposed to do, maybe the loop won't work. you need either a loop followed by `Promise.all` to wait for all the async work started in the loop, or you will need a recursive (or `async`/`await`) solution for sequential looping.

Comment: @Bergi can you please provide the sample on how to proceed ,,as keeping the for loop inside the submitTCDB method does not work ..submitTCtoDB(updateTagForm:any){
console.log("this.selectedFileList is:  "+this.selectedFileList)
    if(this.selectedFileList.length<1){
      alert("Test Case and suite are mandatory")
    }
    else{
    

      for(let i=0;i<this.selectedFileList.length;i++){
        let file=this.selectedFileList[i];
        this.readFile(file).then(() => {  
          alert("");
          this.submitTC(updateTagForm)});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `resolve` call in a loop, but `resolve` only has an effect when called the first time: once a promise resolves, that is its final state, and the `then` callbacks are triggered. So that happens when the *first* file has been read, without waiting for any other files to be processed.

What you could do:

- Promisify the `FileReader` without adding specific logic (your `if` check): keep that outside of it, so it remains generic
- Use `Promise.all` to map the file list to a new promise that will give the list of file contents.
- Process the list of contents for the specific checks
- Return the new promise (`Promise.all` or the one chained on it) to the caller.

Code:

```
submitTCtoDB() {
    console.log("this.selectedFileList is:  " + JSON.stringify(this.selectedFileList))
    this.readFileList(this.selectedFileList).then((validList) => {
        alert("ReadFile Finished now submit TC");
        this.selectedFileList = validList;
        this.submitTC()
    });
}

readFileList(list) {
    return Promise.all(list.map(file => this.readFile(file))).then(contents => {
        return list.filter((file, i) => {
            const fileContent = contents[i];
            if (fileContent.indexOf("END DATA | BEGIN RESULTS") != -1) {
                console.log("Multiple testcases found in " + file.name + " file.  Please separate/save testcases in Calc Builder. Then reimport");
                console.log(fileContent);
                return false; // exclude this file
            }
            return true; // include this file
        });
    });
}

readFile(file) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("file in promiseFile: " + file.name);
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = () => resolve(fileReader.result);
        fileReader.readAsText(file);
    });
}
```

Comment: @trincot----Last query is still not resolved sir..it is taking the wrong file when multiple files are passed

Comment: Please check that the return false happens for the file you want to reject. Output the file name to make sure. The logic is fine.

Comment: yes in false i am getting the rejected file and in true i am getting the other file but when applying splice on the arrray it messes up....Thanks.

Comment: Splice? You should not do splice. It is not in my answer. The filter does the job fine. And result should be assigned in submitTCtoDB. That's all.

Comment: then how i will remove the invalid files from seletedFileList...as seletedFileList should not contain those files when the submitTC method is called.

Comment: Check the code in my answer please. It seems you did not use it fully.

Comment: so sorry ..you are right it worked absolutely fine..Thanks a ton.