# getting incorrect file name while using index to splice the file inside list.filter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise, angular-promise

```js
readFileList(list) {
  return Promise.all(list.map(file => this.readFile(file))).then(contents => {
      return list.filter((file, i) => {
          const fileContent:any = contents[i];
          if (fileContent.indexOf("END DATA | BEGIN RESULTS") != -1) {
              alert("Multiple testcases found in " + file.name + " file.  Please separate/save testcases in Calc Builder. Then reimport");
              console.log(fileContent);
          //     const index: number = this.selectedFileList.indexOf(file);
              alert(file.name);//it is coming fine.
          //     if (index > -1) {
              //this.selectedFileList.splice(this.selectedFileList.indexOf(file), 1);//when splicing then incorrect file is spliced
          //      console.log(file.name+"removed from the list");
               
          //  }  
           return false;// exclude this file

          }
          return true; // include this file
      });
  });
}
```

code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-meh5jn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fimport-test-case%2Fimport-test-case.component.ts

while reading the file through file Input when taking multiple files it is taking incorrect file when trying to splice the file from the arrayList.

complete functionality is mentoned at--[call then only after method returning promise is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54969731/call-then-only-after-method-returning-promise-is-finished)

Comment: @trincot pleased comment